# moving several balls around a board sprite kit Xcode

Tags: sprite-kit, cmmotionmanager

I have a small app that I have several sprite "balls" that move around the board using MotionManager.gravity.
I have code that when one of any of the balls meets an edge the stop at the edge.  also if one of any of the balls gets to the corner it stops in the corner. I have also written code in which if two or three of the balls are on any one edge and touch each other (they have collision detection turned on) they stop in they maintain their relative position to the other ball.

Here is my code for that:

//this allocs the motionManager and set up the gravity values.

```
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.005f;
    self.motionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    self.motionQueue.name = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] stringByAppendingString:@".motion"];
    self.updatePosition = NO;
    [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:self.motionQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
        @synchronized(self) {
            NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

            [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

            [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

            [formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];
            {
                _numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:motion.gravity.x / 15.0 *200]];
                _numberStringy = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:motion.gravity.y / 15.0 *200]];
                n = [_numberString intValue];
                 y = [_numberStringy intValue];
             }
            self.gravity = motion.gravity;
            self.updatePosition = YES;
        }
    }];
    [self startDisplayLink];
```

//this shows how I stop the ball at the edge

```
- (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{


    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!self.updatePosition)
            return;

        self.ball.position = CGPointMake(self.ball.position.x + (n*.99), self.ball.position.y + (y*.99));
        self.ball2.position = CGPointMake(self.ball2.position.x + (n*.98), self.ball2.position.y +(y*.98));
        self.ball3.position = CGPointMake(self.ball3.position.x + n, self.ball3.position.y + y);

        if (ball.position.x <=340) {
            ball.position = CGPointMake(340, ball.position.y);
        }

        if (ball.position.x >=684) {
            ball.position = CGPointMake(684, ball.position.y);
        }
        if (ball.position.y <=148) {
            ball.position = CGPointMake( ball.position.x,148);
        }
        if (ball.position.y >=620) {
            ball.position = CGPointMake(ball.position.x,620);
        }
```

//this stops it in the corner

```
if ( ball.position.x >=684 && ball.position.y <=148 ) {
            ball.position = CGPointMake(684, 148);
        }
        if ( ball.position.x >=684 && ball.position.y >=620 ) {
            ball.position = CGPointMake(684, 620);
        }
        if ( ball.position.x <=340 && ball.position.y <=148 ) {
            ball.position = CGPointMake(340, 148);
        }
        if ( ball.position.x <=340 && ball.position.y >=620 ) {
            ball.position = CGPointMake(340, 620);
        }
```

//and this shows how I have set it up that if they are on one side and ball1 is in the corner and ball2 is next and ball3 is next they keep their relative positions.  I thought if I set the corner ball and the rest had collision detection turned on they would just stop.  They do but they push ball1 in the corner out of its position.  So I wrote the code

```
if (ball2.position.y == ball3.position.y && ball.position.y == ball2.position.y && ball.position.x < ball2.position.x && ball2.position.x < ball3.position.x  ) {
           int s = (self.ball3.position.x - self.ball2.position.x);

           int t = ((self.ball2.position.y - self.ball3.position.y));

           k = t + s;

           int f =(self.ball2.position.x - self.ball.position.x);
           int g = ((self.ball2.position.y - self.ball.position.y));
           j = f+g;

           int h =(self.ball3.position.x - self.ball.position.x);
           int i = ((self.ball3.position.y - self.ball.position.y));
           l = h + i;



            NSLog(@"ball2centerx:%f",ball2.position.x);
            NSLog(@"ball2centery:%f",ball2.position.y);
            NSLog(@"ballcenterx:%f",ball.position.x);
            NSLog(@"ballcentery:%f",ball.position.y);
            NSLog(@"ball3centerx:%f",ball3.position.x);
            NSLog(@"ball3centery:%f",ball3.position.y);

            CGPoint w = CGPointMake(340, 148);
            CGPoint x = CGPointMake(340, 620);
            CGPoint v = CGPointMake(684, 148);
            CGPoint z = CGPointMake(684, 620);
            CGPoint m = CGPointMake(370, 148);
            CGPoint q = CGPointMake(370, 620);
            CGPoint o = CGPointMake(654, 148);
            CGPoint p = CGPointMake(654, 620);



            if (CGPointEqualToPoint(ball.position,w) ) {
                if (f < 30) {
                ball2.position = CGPointMake(370, 148);
                }
            }
            if (CGPointEqualToPoint(ball.position,x)) {
                if (f<30) {
                ball2.position = CGPointMake(370, 620);
                }
            }

            if (CGPointEqualToPoint(ball3.position,v)) {
                if  (s <30){
                ball2.position = CGPointMake(654, 148);
                }
            }


            if (CGPointEqualToPoint(ball3.position,z)) {
                if  (s <30){
                ball2.position = CGPointMake(654, 620);
                }
            }

            if (CGPointEqualToPoint(ball2.position,m)) {
                if  (s <30){
                    ball3.position = CGPointMake(400, 148);
                }

            }

            if (CGPointEqualToPoint(ball2.position,o)) {
                if (f<30) {
                ball.position = CGPointMake(624, 148);
                }
            }

            if (CGPointEqualToPoint(ball2.position,q)) {
                 if  (s <30){
                ball3.position = CGPointMake(400, 620);
                 }
            }

            if (CGPointEqualToPoint(ball2.position,p)) {
                if (f<30) {
                ball.position = CGPointMake(624, 620);
                }
            }

            }
```

The problem is that as I add more ball the code is going to become extremely complex.

is there a way to write it so that if one ball (any ball) is in the corner and another one is in position two it will stay there and so forth.  Kind of like a generic code for all ball configuration. instead of writing it for every configuration?

Comment: Are you creating a variable/property for each ball?

Comment: not sure what you mean.   I don't think so.  each ball is a designated sprite like ball, ball2, ball3 etc made in .h file and synthesized in .m.   Each one moves by adding the motionManager. gravity value to the its x,and y.  Then like shown above as each ball occupies a space something happens.  Can you show me or give me an example to look at.  @property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *ball; is property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to have a number of nodes in your scene, it becomes tedious and impractical to create a property for each one. A good solution is to create each node and add it into an array. The array will allow you to keep a reference to it. The important thing is to create each node with its own unique name. You can do this by creating a counter property.

```
@property (nonatomic) int myCounter;
```

Then when you create your node set the node's name property like this:

```
myCounter++;
myNode.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myNode-%i",myCounter];
```

Once you have fully created the node, add it to a NSMutableArray like this:

```
[self.myArray addObject:myNode];
```

You can add as many nodes to the array as you need.

To enumerate through the array you can do this:

```
for (SKSpriteNode *object in myArray) {
    // let's look for a node with the name of myNode-2
    if([myNode.name isEqualToString:@"myNode-2"]) {
        NSLog(@"Found it");
    }
}
```

---

Here is an example to enumerate the array to check for each node's position and set its speed to zero dependent on the IF statement:

```
for (SKSpriteNode *object in myArray) {
    if((object.position.x >= 300) && (object.position.y >= 300)) {
        object.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Remember that because you are storing the objects in your array as SKSpriteNodes and enumerating your array using SKSpriteNode, you have access to all the corresponding properties like speed, position, name, etc...

Comment: I don't see How this helps.  I want to do this  For any ball node that is in a specific position it will be in that position.  For any ball node that is in a specific position while the other position is filled it will have that position.  For any third ball node in the third position while the other two are in those positions the third ball will be in that position.  and so forth.  I'm sure i'm dense but I don't see how this will to that.

Comment: @user1114881 - Give me one specific example of what you are trying to do. Your question, in its current format, has too many things you want to do.

Comment: Ok thanks for help/patience!  I have four ball nodes  rolling around in a box.  Each ball comes to edge of box it stops (I have ball nodes when  <= or>= to x or y position they stop at that position.  that's ok,  but when all four balls are lined up on one side and roll down to a corner the first stops at the corner and second stops because of collision detection but when the third and forth ball collide with the ball in front of it, the ball in the corner goes beyond the corner.  so I tell each ball to stop in relative position for every possible configuration.  Wish I could show screen shot

Comment: With some tweeking I got this to do what I needed.  Thanks a lot for the info on variables.  Only one problem left.